# Cannot Implicitly Convert "void" to "object". How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller, new-operator

So I have been working on my first game in Unity using C#, and I am having an error with the code but Visual Studio says that the code looks good. Anything I need to change? (If the code looks wonky, I followed a tutorial)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private float m_JumpForce = 400f;                          // Amount of force added when the player jumps.
[Range(0, 1)] [SerializeField] private float m_CrouchSpeed = .36f;          // Amount of maxSpeed applied to crouching movement. 1 = 100%
[Range(0, .3f)] [SerializeField] private float m_MovementSmoothing = .05f;  // How much to smooth out the movement
[SerializeField] private bool m_AirControl = false;                         // Whether or not a player can steer while jumping;
[SerializeField] private LayerMask m_WhatIsGround;                          // A mask determining what is ground to the character
[SerializeField] private Transform m_GroundCheck;                           // A position marking where to check if the player is grounded.
[SerializeField] private Transform m_CeilingCheck;                          // A position marking where to check for ceilings
[SerializeField] private Collider2D m_CrouchDisableCollider;                // A collider that will be disabled when crouching

const float k_GroundedRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if grounded
private bool m_Grounded;            // Whether or not the player is grounded.
const float k_CeilingRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if the player can stand up
private Rigidbody2D m_Rigidbody2D;
private bool m_FacingRight = true;  // For determining which way the player is currently facing.
private Vector3 m_Velocity = Vector3.zero;

[Header("Events")]
[Space]

public UnityEvent OnLandEvent;

[System.Serializable]
public class BoolEvent : UnityEvent<bool> { }

public BoolEvent OnCrouchEvent;
private bool m_wasCrouching = false;

private void Awake()
{
    m_Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    if (OnLandEvent == null)
        OnLandEvent = new UnityEvent();

    if (OnCrouchEvent == null)
        OnCrouchEvent = new BoolEvent();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    bool wasGrounded = m_Grounded;
    m_Grounded = false;

    // The player is grounded if a circlecast to the groundcheck position hits anything designated as ground
    // This can be done using layers instead but Sample Assets will not overwrite your project settings.
    Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_GroundCheck.position, k_GroundedRadius, m_WhatIsGround);
    for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
    {
        if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
        {
            m_Grounded = true;
            if (!wasGrounded)
                OnLandEvent.Invoke();
        }
    }
}


public void Move(float move, bool crouch, bool jump)
{
    // If crouching, check to see if the character can stand up
    if (!crouch)
    {
        // If the character has a ceiling preventing them from standing up, keep them crouching
        if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(m_CeilingCheck.position, k_CeilingRadius, m_WhatIsGround))
        {
            crouch = true;
        }
    }

    //only control the player if grounded or airControl is turned on
    if (m_Grounded || m_AirControl)
    {

        // If crouching
        if (crouch)
        {
            if (!m_wasCrouching)
            {
                m_wasCrouching = true;
                OnCrouchEvent.Invoke(true);
            }

            // Reduce the speed by the crouchSpeed multiplier
            move *= m_CrouchSpeed;

            // Disable one of the colliders when crouching
            if (m_CrouchDisableCollider != null)
                m_CrouchDisableCollider.enabled = false;
        } else
        {
            // Enable the collider when not crouching
            if (m_CrouchDisableCollider != null)
                m_CrouchDisableCollider.enabled = true;

            if (m_wasCrouching)
            {
                m_wasCrouching = false;
                OnCrouchEvent.Invoke(false);
            }
        }

        // Move the character by finding the target velocity
        Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector2(move * 10f, m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
        // And then smoothing it out and applying it to the character
        m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(m_Rigidbody2D.velocity, targetVelocity, ref m_Velocity, m_MovementSmoothing);

        // If the input is moving the player right and the player is facing left...
        if (move > 0 && !m_FacingRight)
        {
            // ... flip the player.
            Flip();
        }
        // Otherwise if the input is moving the player left and the player is facing right...
        else if (move < 0 && m_FacingRight)
        {
            // ... flip the player.
            Flip();
        }
    }
    // If the player should jump...
    if (m_Grounded && jump)
    {
        // Add a vertical force to the player.
        m_Grounded = false;
        m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));
    }
}


private void Flip()
{
    // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing.
    m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;

    // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}
```

}**strong text**

Comment: Where does the error appear, if VS doesn't complain?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Move method in another script?

If you're using that somewhere else and are attempting to assign to something using its result, it will result in that error.

Edit: Might also be the call to OverlapCircle(). It returns a Collider2D, but you're treating it as a boolean value by having it in an if check.
Try using it like:

```
if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(m_CeilingCheck.position, k_CeilingRadius, m_WhatIsGround) != null)
```

Comment: I will try this out when I can. The tutorial didn’t fully explain everything so this could fix it. Plus, I don’t have any other script except for the character controller.